# Indentation of numbers in a numbered list

Tags: indentation, enumerate

I have a numbered list in a LaTeX document and it automatically indents the numbers.  How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 4):

Typically one would go with [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) on this, since it allows for localized (or global) changes to lists very easily.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=*}
\begin{document}

\noindent
This is some paragraph text with no indent.

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \item Third item that is very long and should span at least two lines within this environment.
  \item Last item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```